# Creating a crude bogo_sort using Python 3.7's asynchronous for-loop

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop, asynchronous

Basically I wrote the following short code sample.  I'm imaging that I could *"try out"* python's simple "`async for`" loop...

```
import sys

async def avalues(unsorted_list):
    for value in unsorted_list:
        yield value
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def bogo_sort(unsorted_list):
    async for value in avalues(unsorted_list):
        await asyncio.sleep(ord(value[0])-ord("A"))
        print(value)
        sys.stdout.flush()

import asyncio

unsorted_list="Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","Indigo","Alfa","Bravo","Charlie","Delta"

if __name__=="__main__":
    print("BEGIN")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(bogo_sort(unsorted_list))
    print("END")
```

I am thinking that maybe `sys.stdio.flush` cannot be run asynchronously.  (Or the `avalues` function did not end up as asynchronous?)  Hints welcome...

The actual output I get is:

```
BEGIN Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel Indigo Alfa Bravo Charlie Delta END
```

I was expecting:

```
BEGIN Alfa Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel Indigo END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async for` does run asynchronously (other async processes can proceed in the meantime), but not in parallel.

To make this work, you would have to make an array of awaitables and then await their results at the same time with something like `asyncio.wait`:

```py
import sys, asyncio

async def avalue(value):
    await asyncio.sleep(ord(value[0])-ord("A"))
    print(value)
    sys.stdout.flush()

async def bogo_sort(unsorted_list):
    awaitables = [avalue(name) for name in unsorted_list]
    await asyncio.wait(awaitables)

unsorted_list="Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","Indigo","Alfa","Bravo","Charlie","Delta"

if __name__=="__main__":
    print("BEGIN")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(bogo_sort(unsorted_list))
    print("END")
```